# Cannot load extension to chromium in headful mode inside Github actions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, playwright

I'm trying to test my chrome extension using Github Actions.

This is how I setup the tests and the fixtures:

```js
extensionContext: async ({ exe_path }, use) => {
  const pathToExtension = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build');
  const extensionContext = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
    ],
    executablePath: exe_path,
  });
  await use(await extensionContext.newContext());
  await extensionContext.close();
},
```

I'm running the system test inside Github actions using a Makefile, the target runs the next command:

```bash
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 0, 1920x1080x24' yarn run test --project=${BROWSER}
```

The setup is as follows (Also from the Makefile):

```bash
yarn install --frozen-lockfile
yarn run playwright install --with-deps
```

When I run the above code, `chromium.launch` hangs and the test fails after the 30s timeout.
When I remove the `--disable-extensions-except` flag `launch` succeeds, but the extension is not loaded (although the `--load-extension` flag remains).

Is there a working example on how to test extensions in headful mode inside any CI/CD framework (preferably Github actions)?

Additional Info:

- Playwright Version: 1.28.0
- Operating System: Linux (ubuntu-latest runner in Github actions)
- Node.js version: 18.12.0
- Browser: chromium

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you ever manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I used `docker-compose` in my setup and switching to `docker compose` fixed it